# SVG dragging to desktop is now broken in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, draggable

I built a web app that allows users to search a library of svg icons and then drag and drop svg icons to the desktop. To drag and drop the svg, I simply put the svg link in an img tag. The code looks basically like this - `<img src="icons/action/add_contact.svg" />`

This was a simple solution that worked great in Chrome and Safari for about a year. Recently it has stopped working in Chrome and I was wondering if anyone else is experiencing the same thing; or if someone has another solution to drag svg images to the desktop. Any help would be great as this application is widely used at my company and is currently broken.

I also built a codepen - `https://codepen.io/ashlynaiu/pen/rmEQWG`

Comment: The codepen works for me in Chrome Beta 59.0.3071.71 on Windows 10.

Comment: Bummer, I'll submit a bug report to Chrome then.